# The year after carrots go to seed

Tags: seed-saving

I let some of my carrots go to seed this year to gather up the seeds myself, beautiful white flowers, lots of pollinators, etc. =D

Going into the following spring however what can I expect of the carrots that went to seed this year? Do these Biennial crops die off after producing seeds? Will they go back through the cycle again: new taproot, then a seeds the following year?

Comment: "new taproot" - yes, from the seeds you plant to grow new carrots. From the used-up taproot the plant last year stored energy in so that it could put all that energy into making seeds this year - no, not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biennials always die after they set seed.

Comment: +1 My experience with radishes exactly. Furthermore the bulb becomes useless for eating. Beautiful flowers though.

Answer (score 2):

They can not sprout after they have died. The taproot is not a bulb.